# How can I run rr() in erl_call success?

Tags: erlang

Is there any way to run rr/1 success in using erl_call? or is there any similar function like rr can be used in erl_call? I want to load some records in erl_call.
Or is there any way to define a record in erl_call. Seems rd/1 also can not be used in erl_call :(
e.g.
echo "rr(MODULE)." | erl_call -e

rr is shell function, seems can not be used in erl_call

Answer (score 0):

rr, rd, rp... are only useful for the shell, it allows the shell to **interpret** a records correctly.

But remember that a records "exists" only at compile time, during execution of the program, it exits only [tuples](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/records.html#id86474), all the syntax such as `A#my_record{a_label = Value}` is replaced by tuple functions like `setelement(3,A,Value)`.

To achieve this, the compiler must find in the file (or in an included file) the record definition.

If the compiler does not find the record definition when it has to compile a record syntax, it generates an error.

The pseudo function record_info/2 is only available during compilation, it is replaced by its result after compilation.

Last, if you want to share a record between several modules *(though it is not recommended)* the general solution is to put the record definition in a header file: File.hrl and include this file in modules when necessary.

Since [maps](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#id70023) exist *(they were introduced with Erlang/OTP R17)*, I think that they are a better solution to share structured information between modules, at least in many cases.